# Where will a new element be inserted in a std::set?

Tags: c++, iterator, set

I have a loop like this (where mySet is a std::set):

```
for(auto iter=mySet.begin(); iter!=mySet.end(); ++iter){
    if (someCondition){mySet.insert(newElement);}
    if (someotherCondition){mySet.insert(anothernewElement);}
}
```

I am experiencing some strange behavior, and I am asking myself if this could be due to the inserted element being inserted "before" the current iterator position in the loop. Namely, I have an Iteration where both conditions are true, but still the distance

```
distance(iter, mySet.end())
```

is only 1, not 2 as I would expect. Is my guess about set behavior right? And more importantly, can I still do what I want to do?

what I'm trying to do is to build "chains" on a hexagonal board beween fields of the same color. I have a set containing all fields of my color, and the conditions check the color of neighboring fields, and if they are of the same color, copy this field to mySet, so the chain.

I am trying to use std::set for this because it allows no fields to be in the chain more than once. Reading the comments so far I fear I need to swich to std::vector, where append() will surely add the element at the end, but then I will run into new problems due to having to think of a way to forbid doubling of elements. I therefore am hoping for advice how to solve this the best way.

Comment: It's often a bad idea to modify a container while iterating over it. Is this std::set? It inserts in sorted position. Can you make a [mcve] and we can comment better on where and why it is inserted, and why distance is whatever it is.

Comment: Elements are inserted in the lexical order (sorted). Depending on where you are that could be before or after the current element.

Comment: The [cppreference page on insert](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set/insert) says "No iterators or references are invalidated." So you're definitely still in the land of defined behavior. That being said, it doesn't say anything about *where* that element will be inserted.

Comment: What kind of set?

Comment: It is a std::set indeed. In my particular case, modifying it while iterating is basically exactly what I want, but of course I need to add averything after the current position. Is there a way to achieve that?

Comment: @justsomerandomguy If you want to avoid double instances in vector, check if the value already exists before inserting. Check Antonio Perez's answer to see how to do the check.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on the new element's value, it may be inserted before or after current iterator value. Below is an example of inserting before and after an iterator.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <set>

int main()
{
  std::set<int> s;
  s.insert(3);

  auto it = s.begin();
  std::cout << std::distance(it, s.end()) << std::endl; // prints 1

  s.insert(2); // 2 will be inserted before it
  std::cout << std::distance(it, s.end()) << std::endl; // prints 1

  s.insert(5); // 5 will be inserted after it
  std::cout << std::distance(it, s.end()) << std::endl; // prints 2

}
```

Regarding your question in the comments: `In my particular case, modifying it while iterating is basically exactly what I want, but of course I need to add averything after the current position`; no you can not manually arrange the order of the elements. A new value's order is determined by comparing the new one and existing elements. Below is the quote from [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set).

> std::set is an associative container that contains a sorted set of unique objects of type Key. Sorting is done using the key comparison function Compare. Search, removal, and insertion operations have logarithmic complexity. Sets are usually implemented as red-black trees.

Thus, the implementation of the set will decide where exactly it will be placed.

If you really need to add values after current position, you need to use a different container. For example, simply a vector would be suitable:

```
it = myvector.insert ( it+1 , 200 ); // +1 to add after it
```

Answer (score 2):

If you have a small number of items, doing a brute-force check to see if they're inside a vector can actually be *faster* than checking if they're in a set. This is because vectors tend to have better cache locality than lists.

We can write a function to do this pretty easily:

```
template<class T>
void insert_unique(std::vector<T>& vect, T const& elem) {
    if(std::find(vect.begin(), vect.end(), elem) != vect.end()) {
        vect.push_back(elem); 
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you for this answer, I thik however there is a small typo, it should be "==" instead if "!=", right?